# Swift variable is nil when data type is not specified

Tags: ios, swift, types, type-inference

jsonString is nil in the following line

```
 let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:currentMedia?.rawDataFile ?? ""))
```

when specify the data type as in the below code,  `jsonString` is not nil and has a value:

```
 let jsonString:String = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:currentMedia?.rawDataFile ?? ""))
```

The problem is in first line although

```
try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:currentMedia?.rawDataFile ?? ""))
```

is evaluated to non-empty string value but nil is assigned to `jsonString`. When explicit type `String`  is used for  `jsonString` ,the expected non-empty value is assigned to `jsonString`.
I need help understanding this behaviour.

Comment: I think you are missing something in your question, your both sentences are the same?

Comment: yes I forgot the data type.

Comment: Your latter code causes compile-time error. Please confirm the code really reproduces the issue before posting it.

Comment: There is no error with two types. `let jsonString2:String? = try? String(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S your String data type is optional in the question it is not...

Comment: @inspector_60 , If i use `let jsonString2:String = try? String(contentsOf: url)`  this makes compile time error. So the code won't run. So, if i use `let jsonString2:String = try! String(contentsOf: url)` then there is no compile time error. `Optional` or `implicitly unwrapped` there is no runtime error when the `file` is in bundle.  . i.e., `let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf:url)` or `let jsonString2:String = try! String(contentsOf: url)`.

Comment: Should I repeat? Your second line of code does not compile. So, with the code _`jsonString` is not nil and has a value_ does not make sense. `try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:currentMedia?.rawDataFile ?? ""))` returns `nil` when errors or returns non-nil value when no errors, regardless of the type annotation. If you insist that type annotation affects, you need to show comparable two codes.

Comment: How have your confirmed that _`try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:currentMedia?.rawDataFile ?? ""))` is evaluated to non-empty string value_?

Answer (score 1):

Swift can determine the type if you don't tell it explicitly.

In the following case (1), Swift figures out the type because it is not explicit. The type in this case is String? which can be nil.

```
// 1
let jsonString = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString ?? ""))
```

In example 2, the type is explicit (String).  The expression on the right of the = results in type String? which cannot be assigned to a variable of type String.

```
// 2
let jsonString2: String = try? String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString ?? ""))
```

Furthermore,

```
// this won't compile
let xstring: String = nil

// no value supplied so it is nil
let xstring2: String?

// no value supplied so it is nil (same as above)
let xstring3: String? = nil
```